# Why is Java so slow in reading from serial port?

Tags: java, time, serial-port, port, execution

So I'm using the SerialPort class to read data from a serial device. my code is as shown below. I researched a little and found out that serial data is read at 100kb/sec. So according to that, my program would have to read the data in just 2 seconds since I have called the readHexString function with 200000 as a parameter and it thus reads 200000 bytes, I just want to know why it takes many minutes to read the data serially?

```
serialPort.openPort();
        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_57600, 
                             SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                             SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                             SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);


        int count = 0;
        String data = serialPort.readHexString(200000);
```

Comment: This is a very rough calculation. Your Baud rate is set to 57600 bits per sec. You have 200,000 bytes to send (that is 2,000,000 bits). 2,000,000 / 57600 = just under 35 seconds.

Comment: Serial data is read at the baud rate you specify, not '100kb/sec'. You specified a *much lower* baud rate than 100kb/sec. What did you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can not assume 100kb/sec

[image: D=Bd*o/(o+d)]

[image]

That leads to 34,722 seconds for 2000000 Bytes

I'd like to ask if your device is sending continuously Data? Your Code reads 200.000 Bytes. So you have to wait until the Buffer is full. You could try to cycle smaller amount of data and break if a marker is reached.